# Character with animation track and virtual camera move back to it's original position when changing animations with Timeline, Fix/Work around?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the first screenshot the Timeline the start. When I hit play or dragging the time slider all 3 characters the two soldiers and the female in the middle will start walking. When they get to the HumanoidIdle animation part the two soldiers will change to idle on the last(current) position they are but the female the one in the middle that also the virtual cameras to follow will change it's her position back to the original start position.

I saw this work around but I can't figure how to do it and what should I do. Take empty new GameObject and do what ? : "The only workaround I can give you right now is to have a parent gameobject that would be used to record the position and keep the Humanoid object for animation clips."

[image: Timeline]

Why she move back when changing to idle ?

You can see the problem here on the second screenshot:

[image: Timeline]

In the third screenshot the Navi vcam (first virtual camera) settings. I'm following the female character the one in the middle:

[image: Timeline]

On the last screenshot the Navi vcam (1) This is the second virtual camera with this one I'm following and Look At the female character in the middle:

[image: Timeline]

I can't figure out why when it's changing the animations from walk to idle the character with the virtual camera/s change it's own position back to the start original position and not staying in the last/current position like the soldiers?

Comment: Found a solution but why it's not built in automatic already in the Timeline ? 

What I did is on each of the Idle animations on each Animation track is right mouse click then: Match Offsets To Previous Clip.
Then on the Female animation track I also did on Track Offsets: Apply Scene Offsets
On the two soldiers animation tracks i did on Track Offsets: Apply Transform Offsets

Took me sometime to found out this combination to work.

Why it's not automatic set already ? Why do I have to mess with it too much to find work around ? Am I missing something ? Did something wrong ?

Comment: Why it's so complicated the Timeline and all the settings of the offsets positions rotations and stuff. Why they didn't make it automatic already ? Is there anything in the asset store maybe that make everything easier ?